# Read item fields in Umbraco template Programmatically

Tags: umbraco

Im trying to read a value programmatically in an umbraco template

So, instead of

```
<umbraco:Item runat="server" Field="url"></umbraco:Item>
```

Id like to write

```
<%=umbraco.item.Field %>
```

Or similar :)

I have searched most of the web now but found nothing. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current page object isn't passed into the master page or .NET macros (before Umbraco 4.6.0, 4.6.0 does kind of support that).

The only way you can do what you're after would be with:

```
<%= umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Node.GetCurrent().GetProperty("Field").Value %>
```